# How should I detect an observable is idle and inject data every minute?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system.reactive

I have an observable returning data sporadically. If there is no data for one minute, I need to repeat the last data, every minute until it generates data again. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a timer for idle time check and a field to store last published value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner to do what you want. I've tested it and it seems to be correct.

```
var results = source
    .Publish(xs =>
        xs
            .Select(x =>
                Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))
                    .Select(_ => x)
                    .StartWith(x))
            .Switch());
```

Let me know if this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the observable in an observable that is guaranteed to return a value at least once per minute. The wrapper could do this by running a timer that is restarted whenever the wrapped observable returns a value.

Thus, the wrapper returns data whenever the wrapped observable returns data or when a minute has passed after the last event.

The rest of the application conveniently just observes the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (non-threadsafe, in case your source is multithreaded) implementation of a `RepeatAfterTimeout` operator:

**EDIT** Updated as Timeout didn't work as I expected

```
// Repeats the last value emitted after a timeout 
public static IObservable<TSource> RepeatAfterTimeout<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan timeout, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<TSource>(observer =>
    {
        var timer = new MutableDisposable();
        var subscription = new MutableDisposable();

        bool hasValue = false;
        TSource lastValue = default(TSource);

        timer.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(recurse =>
        {
            if (hasValue)
            {
                observer.OnNext(lastValue);
            }

            recurse();
        });

        subscription.Disposable = source
            .Do(value => { lastValue = value; hasValue = true; })
            .Subscribe(observer);

        return new CompositeDisposable(timer, subscription);
    });
}

public static IObservable<TSource> RepeatAfterTimeout<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return source.RepeatAfterTimeout(timeout, Scheduler.TaskPool);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will meet the requirements (even if you actually used the timeout somewhere).  You are outputting a value every period via the timer, regardless of activity from source.  Also, you are using an out of date version or Rx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same requirement once.  I chose to include a default value to use if no value triggers before the first timeout.  Here's the C# version:

```
public static IObservable<T> 
AtLeastEvery<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan timeout, 
                T defaultValue, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (scheduler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("scheduler");
    return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
        {
            ulong id = 0;
            var gate = new Object();
            var timer = new SerialDisposable();
            T lastValue = defaultValue;

            Action createTimer = () =>
                {
                    ulong startId = id;
                    timer.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(timeout,
                          self =>
                          {
                              bool noChange;
                              lock (gate)
                              {
                                  noChange = (id == startId);
                                  if (noChange) obs.OnNext(lastValue);
                              }
                              //only restart if no change, otherwise
                              //the change restarted the timeout
                              if (noChange) self(timeout);
                          });
                };
            //start the first timeout
            createTimer();
            var subscription = source.Subscribe(
                v =>
                {
                    lock (gate)
                    {
                        id += 1;
                        lastValue = v;
                    }
                    obs.OnNext(v);
                    createTimer(); //reset the timeout
                },
                ex =>
                {
                    lock (gate)
                    {
                        id += 1; //'cancel' timeout
                    }
                    obs.OnError(ex);
                    //do not reset the timeout, because the sequence has ended
                },
                () =>
                {
                    lock (gate)
                    {
                        id += 1; //'cancel' timeout
                    }
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                    //do not reset the timeout, because the sequence has ended
                });

            return new CompositeDisposable(timer, subscription);
        });
}
```

If you don't want to have to pass a scheduler every time, just make an overload that picks a default one and delegates to this method.  I used `Scheduler.ThreadPool`.

This code works by using the behavior of `SerialDisposable` to "cancel" the previous timeout call when a new value from the source comes in.  There is also a counter I use in case the timer has already elapsed (in which case Disposing the return from Schedule will not help) but the method has not yet actually run.

I investigated the possibilities of changing timeouts but did not need them for the problem I was working on.  I recall that it was possible but don't have any of that code handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work the Rx way (no recursion but still involving a side effect):

```
    public static IObservable<TSource> RepeatLastValueWhenIdle<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        TimeSpan idleTime,
        TSource defaultValue = default(TSource))
    {
        TSource lastValue = defaultValue;

        return source
            // memorize the last value on each new 
            .Do(ev => lastValue = ev) 
            // re-publish the last value on timeout
            .Timeout(idleTime,  Observable.Return(lastValue))
            // restart waiting for a new value
            .Repeat(); 
    }
```